# Puppet:Server hostname 'puppetmaster' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetmaster.us-east-2.compute.internal, DNS:puppet,

Tags: puppet

I use `puppet` in AWS, and I get the following error when Puppet runs:

```
Puppet:Server hostname 'puppetmaster' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetmaster.us-east-2.compute.internal, DNS:puppet,
```

Please find the following configurations:

```
#master /etc/hosts
ubuntu@puppetmaster:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
172.31.16.177  puppetmaster puppet 
172.31.19.211  ip-172-31-19-211 #client

#client
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-211:~$ cat /etc/hosts
 127.0.0.1 localhost
 172.31.16.177  puppetmaster puppet
 172.31.19.211  ip-172-31-19-211
 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-211:~$ cat /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf
# This file can be used to override the default puppet settings.
# See the following links for more details on what settings are available:
# - https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/config_important_settings.html
# - https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/config_about_settings.html
# - https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/config_file_main.html
# - https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/configuration.html
[main]
certname = ip-172-31-19-211
server = puppetmaster
```

> The above are the host files of master and node machine and I have configured puppet.conf file as well in the node machine but still the client machine is not connected to the master.Please someone help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Try with `server = puppetmaster.us-east-2.compute.internal`. What it says is that you configured for your connection to go to `puppetmaster` (I advise you to use fqdn) and seems it is not resolved as `puppetmaster.us-east-2.compute.internal`.

Comment: Also, when you generated your cert, you didn't use DNS alternative names ( as `puppet_master_dnsaltnames` ) when installing or upgrading puppet. It is used in `pe.conf` (more on [official docs](https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2019.8/installing_pe.html))

Answer (score 1):

Puppet uses cryptographic certificates on both the client side and the server side to authenticate machine identities.  The error message shows that this authentication is failing because the certificate the server presents to the client does not identify it as the machine the client expects.

Specifically, the machine expects the server to be identified as "puppetmaster", but that is not one of the identities listed in the cert.  ("puppetmaster.us-east-2.compute.internal" is among those identities, but this is not equivalent for the purpose).

There is considerable flexibility in how all this is set up, but for the smoothest experience, one should

- Configure the Puppet server and all Puppet clients with fully-qualified, DNS-resolvable hostnames.  Do this on each machine *before* installing any Puppet software on that machine, or at least before starting any Puppet component for the first time.
- Do not change Puppet client or server hostnames after Puppet is set up.
- Always use the chosen fully-qualified name to connect to the Puppet server.  In particular, specify this as the server name in clients' `puppet.conf` configuration files.

The question is unclear about the exact circumstances in which the error is observed, but probably it occurs on a new client, while initially trying to connect it to the server.  In that case the easiest solution would probably be to [update the client's `puppet.conf`](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/config_important_settings.html#settings_agents_all_nodes) to specify the server via the name on its cert: "puppetmaster.us-east-2.compute.internal".  That supposes the server can indeed be reached via that name; if not, then a new cert will probably need to be generated for the server.

Comment: Please also review this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75135457/puppet-server-hostname-puppetmaster-did-not-match-server-certificate