# Puppet Server hostname 'puppetmaster' did not match server certificate

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

I'm trying to install puppet7 master and a client on 2 VirtualBox VM's following this guide https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-puppet-on-ubuntu-20-04/. When I start puppet on the client I get this error. Note the trailing period.

```
Server hostname 'puppetmaster' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetmaster.
```

Listing certnames on the master

```
sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppetserver ca list --all 
Signed Certificates:
    puppetmaster.
```

How can I fix the mismatch?

edit: Attempting to run the commands suggested below I get

```
mark@puppetmaster:~$ puppetserver ca clean --certname puppetmaster.
Traceback (most recent call last):
    9: from /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/cli/apps/ca:5:in `<main>'
    8: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-2.3.6/lib/puppetserver/ca/cli.rb:100:in `run'
    7: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-2.3.6/lib/puppetserver/ca/action/clean.rb:91:in `run'
    6: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-2.3.6/lib/puppetserver/ca/action/clean.rb:103:in `clean_certs'
    5: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-2.3.6/lib/puppetserver/ca/action/clean.rb:103:in `new'
    4: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-2.3.6/lib/puppetserver/ca/certificate_authority.rb:26:in `initialize'
    3: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-2.3.6/lib/puppetserver/ca/certificate_authority.rb:26:in `new'
    2: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-2.3.6/lib/puppetserver/ca/utils/http_client.rb:25:in `initialize'
    1: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-2.3.6/lib/puppetserver/ca/utils/http_client.rb:156:in `make_store'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-2.3.6/lib/puppetserver/ca/utils/http_client.rb:156:in `add_file': system lib (OpenSSL::X509::StoreError)
mark@puppetmaster:~$ sudo puppetserver ca clean --certname puppetmaster.
[sudo] password for mark: 
sudo: puppetserver: command not found
```

I successfully ran the commands in the answer but the incorrect certificate was not removed.

```
mark@puppetmaster:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for mark: 
root@puppetmaster:~# puppetserver ca clean --certname puppetmaster.
Certificate for puppetmaster. has been revoked
Cleaned files related to puppetmaster.
root@puppetmaster:~# puppet ssl clean
Notice: Removed private key /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/puppetmaster..pem
Notice: Removed public key /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/public_keys/puppetmaster..pem
Notice: Removed certificate /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/puppetmaster..pem
root@puppetmaster:~# puppet resource service puppetserver ensure=stopped
Notice: /Service[puppetserver]/ensure: ensure changed 'running' to 'stopped'
service { 'puppetserver':
  ensure   => 'stopped',
  provider => 'systemd',
}
root@puppetmaster:~# puppetserver ca generate --certname puppetmaster --ca-client
Successfully saved certificate for puppetmaster to /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/puppetmaster.pem
Successfully saved certificate for puppetmaster to /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ca/signed/puppetmaster.pem
Successfully saved private key for puppetmaster to /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/puppetmaster.pem
Successfully saved public key for puppetmaster to /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/public_keys/puppetmaster.pem
root@puppetmaster:~# puppet resource service puppetserver ensure=running
Notice: /Service[puppetserver]/ensure: ensure changed 'stopped' to 'running'
service { 'puppetserver':
  ensure   => 'running',
  provider => 'systemd',
}
root@puppetmaster:~# sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppetserver ca list --all
Signed Certificates:
    puppetmaster.       (SHA256)  0B:E3:DC:2D:52:27:D9:D9:A1:18:9D:AB:74:07:50:86:E5:7C:32:5C:6F:A1:23:75:3D:4C:C3:90:7D:4D:08:BF   alt names: ["DNS:puppet", "DNS:puppetmaster."]  authorization extensions: [pp_cli_auth: true]
    puppetmaster        (SHA256)  06:EF:8C:3C:6D:83:CA:7A:C9:A4:39:02:DA:7B:F5:E6:D4:3C:27:B3:80:82:EB:4D:C0:92:99:37:F3:D2:96:F2   alt names: ["DNS:puppetmaster"] authorization extensions: [pp_cli_auth: true]
root@puppetmaster:~# sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppetserver ca sign --all 
Error:
    No waiting certificate requests to sign
```

On the agent, I still get the same error

```
mark@puppetclient:~$ sudo systemctl status puppet 
[sudo] password for mark: 
● puppet.service - Puppet agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/puppet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-01-16 16:53:07 UTC; 1min 6s ago
       Docs: man:puppet-agent(8)
   Main PID: 654 (puppet)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 2237)
     Memory: 83.4M
        CPU: 1.485s
     CGroup: /system.slice/puppet.service
             └─654 /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/ruby /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet agent --no-daemonize

Jan 16 16:53:07 puppetclient systemd[1]: Started Puppet agent.
Jan 16 16:53:13 puppetclient puppet-agent[654]: Starting Puppet client version 7.21.0
Jan 16 16:53:13 puppetclient puppet-agent[654]: Server hostname 'puppetmaster' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetmaster., DNS:puppet, DNS:puppetmaster.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you ended up at the point you did, but I agree that the trailing period in the server's certname looks like the source of the issue.  You probably need to [regenerate the server's agent cert](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/ssl_regenerate_certificates.html#regenerate_agent_certs_and_add_dns_alt_names). (The agent cert is used to authenticate machines to each other, both client and server).  The linked docs provide more detail, but the basic steps are:

1. Revoke and remove the current server certificate

   ```
   puppetserver ca clean --certname puppetmaster.
   ```
2. Remove the agent-side copy of the cert and its associated metadata

   ```
   puppet ssl clean
   ```
3. Stop the `puppetserver` service.  You may use the appropriate service-management tool directly (`systemctl` for Ubuntu 20) but Puppet recommends using `puppet resource`:

   ```
   puppet resource service puppetserver ensure=stopped
   ```
4. Generate a new, signed certificate for the server:

   ```
   puppetserver ca generate --certname <new-certname> [--subject-alt-names <comma-delimited-DNS-names>] --ca-client
   ```

   When you do this, make sure that either the specified `--certname` or one of the specified `--subject-alt-names`, if any, exactly matches the name your clients will use to connect to the server.  Note also that if you specify a certname explicitly in the server's `puppet.conf` then it, too, will need to match the certname specified here.

Although it's not technically part of regenerating the cert, presumably you will afterward want to

5. Restart the `puppetserver` service.  For example, via

   ```
   puppet resource service puppetserver ensure=running
   ```

Comment: Please see error above. I followed the guide exactly on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: @markhorrocks, `sudo <command>` gets you a clean environment for the command.  Instead, use `sudo -i` to obtain a root shell with all the default environment configuration, and run the appropriate Puppet commands there.  Also remember this if ever you want to run `puppet agent` from the command line.

Comment: The error on the client persists, see edits to my question. A client reboot did not help.

Comment: @markhorrocks, Make sure the server's `puppet.conf` does not specify `puppetmaster.` as that machine's certname, as already described in this answer.  If you apply a change, then restart `puppetserver` afterward.  You may also need to [clean out the client's certificates](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/ssl_regenerate_certificates.html#clear_regenerate_certs_for_agents), which may include a copy of the server's old cert.  I had supposed that the old server cert would not be kept because of the previous rejection, but that's not certain.

Comment: Alternatively, @markhorrocks, you might have better luck if you used fully-qualified hostnames as I [recommended previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75135843/2402272), both as the machines' own sense of their hostnames and in your Puppet certificates and configuration.

Comment: @markhorrocks Based on your current question information and the answer above, I would hypothesize that step 4 in the answer was unsuccessfully executed since the cert is associated with the incorrect name (but perhaps correct SANs).